# Word vba delete button not working

Tags: vba, button, ms-word

I got "error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" after running:

```
For Each obj In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    If obj.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "Button" Then '<-error line
        obj.Delete
    End If
Next
```

I thought that I need to declare obj as InlineShape or as Object, but results were the same.
I am sure that I have command button with name Button and I know diference between name and caption, neither works.
This code is part of the code that runs after the same button is pressed.

Comment: Looking at your code, if the delete buttons name is `Button` and the posted code is the code it fires, the macro should delete the clicked button?

Comment: Yes, it should. Macro does something else and then it should delete clicked button. User cannot run that macro twice. I used something similiar in excel and it works.

Comment: If user click command button "Button", macro starts and does something and than delete command button "Button".

Comment: It's Command Button (ActiveX Control). How can I loop throught controls?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the below code which works:

```
Sub delete()

Dim obj As Object

For Each obj In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    If obj.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "Button" Then
        obj.delete
    End If
Next obj

End Sub
```

Comment: ActiveDocument doesn't support .Controls

Comment: Sorry I've amended, you should be using `InlineShapes` (my error). I've tested the edited code which works for me when there's an activex command button called 'Button' on the document.

Comment: That is the same code as I posted :) I still get error.

Comment: It's not, it defines `obj` as an object which you hadn't in your code. Have you tried it with defining `obj`?